# Trouble with ternary operator/shorthand if

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement

```
if ((file.Exists) ? 
lblresults.Text = "the file is there" : 
lblresults.Text = "the file is not there");
```

I keep getting the error stating cannot implicitly convert string to bool

any help would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

lblResults.Text = file.Exists ? "the file is there" : "the file is not there";

Basically you don't need the if.

Answer (score 1):

It expects a bool back. Try this:

```
lblResult.Text = ((file.Exists) ? "the file is there" : "the file is not there");
```